# Webpack config not rendering background-image

Tags: html, css, webpack-2, webpack-5, sass-loader

I am trying to display a background image in my web app from my scss file, it is not working, but when I use it in my inline style, it works. When I try to render the background image from my scss file, I get this error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/f1.jpg' in 'D:\furnitureStore\styles' resolve '../../assets/f1.jpg' in 'D:\furnitureStore\styles'.

I don't know why it is not picking the path  " background: url('../../assets/f1.jpg')" from my scss file.

Here is the content of my webpack.config file below

```
 module.exports = {
 entry: [path.join(dirApp, 'index.js'), path.join(dirStyles, 'index.scss')],

  resolve: {
    modules: [dirApp, dirShared, dirStyles, dirNode]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      IS_DEVELOPMENT
    }),

    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: './shared',
          to: ''
        }
      ]
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),

    new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
      minimizer: {
        implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
        options: {
          // Lossless optimization with custom option
          // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
          plugins: [
            ['gifsicle', { interlaced: true }],
            ['jpegtran', { progressive: true }],
            ['optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 }]
          ]
        }
      }
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: ''
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },

          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|fnt|webp)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name (file) {
            return '[hash].[ext]'
          }
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: ImageMinimizerPlugin.loader
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },

      {
        test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
        loader: 'glslify-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },

  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
  }
}
```

Here is an image of my folder structure
[image]